# Azure Servicebus Competing consumers with round robin

Tags: .net, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

Are competing consumers of an Azure ServiceBus Queue / Subscription *meant* to round-robin?

I'm looping back to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59666477/520050) I asked a while back, and doing a little more testing.

There, I understood that a positive **PrefetchCount** was causing one client to have an affinity to all messages (unless load increases sufficiently for that client to be too busy to handle everything).

It actually looks like setting the SubscriptionClient's 
`MaxConcurrentCalls` to anything other than 1 results in only one client receiving **all** messages under low load.

Setting the `MaxConcurrentCalls = 1` suddenly causes alternative messages to be sent to competing consumers.
(Note that I'm not setting a `PrefetchCount` at all here)

Is this expected? We're scaling out, and I need a client to handle multiple messages concurrently, but 90% of the time, only one instance of a service is handling everything....the others are idle.

FWIW, Here's a sample project on [Github](https://github.com/devsaff/CompetingConsumers) based off the stock-standard MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions)

Answer (score 0):

When setting `MaxConcurrentCalls` to a single message without a prefetch (`PrefetchCount`) you're asking a broker to provide just a single message to the requesting consumer. Assuming there are multiple messages on the broker, each consumer will get one message to process and receive another message once the previous message is completed, and so on. Depending on the latency and processing speed, messages will be distributed among the consumers as those request them. There will be no affinity or round-robin assignment. First come first served is what's happening.

> Is this expected?

Yes.

> We're scaling out, and I need a client to handle multiple messages concurrently, but 90% of the time, only one instance of a service is handling everything....the others are idle.

Setting up `PrefetchCount` and `MaxConcurrentCalls` that are not too greedy will give you some distribution, but if you're looking for an even distribution among instances of your consumer, that won't happen. That was already answered in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59669560/59563) you're referred to.

Comment: It's a pity that I can't have even distribution(or really any distribution at all) at low load, whilst still setting MaxConcurrent to > 1 to cater for increased load during spikes (common in our environment). 
I'll leave it here, but the behavior with a MaxConcurrent == 1 definitely is truly round-robin when processing time < message frequency.. It behaves differently to a value of 2+ -- where one client (usually the first connected) gets all the messages.